# Missing library libkolfprivate.so and the symptoms?

Tags: linux, terminal, arch-linux

Every time I want to install something in pacman I get this info:

```
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libkolfprivate.so is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libkolfprivate.so.4 is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libkolfprivate.so.4.8.0 is empty, not checked.
```

What can it be and how can I repair it?

I can't change jobs (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> gives me a blank screens) is this related?

Answer (score 0):

`libkolfprivate.so` belongs to `kdegames-kolf` package, which is a game for KDE. Probably the file is empty or corrupted, so `ldconfig` complains: try `pacman -Sf kdegames-kolf` to reinstall it (the `f` flag is to force overwriting older files).

However, due to the nature of the library, I'd assume it's unrelated to your "can't change VTs using ctrl-alt-F*" problem.